# DataTable - sWidth definition doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using a datatable plugin to display my data.
The third column may contain long String and the result is that the columns from the right disapear to right of the screen.

I tried to use the "sWidth" parameter to fixe the width of my columns and specifically the third column there is no error but nothing change.

Here's my code:

```
$(".mydataTable").dataTable({ 
      "aoColumnDefs": [
     {"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
      ],            
     "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],                  
     "bJQueryUI": true,
     "bPaginate": false,
     "bStateSave": true,
     "bInfo": false,
     "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100],
     "iDisplayLength" : 10,
     "bAutoWidth" : false,
     "aoColumns": [
    { "sWidth": "70px" },
    { "sWidth": "90px" },
    { "sWidth": "220px"  },
    { "sWidth": "90px"  },
    { "sWidth": "90px"  },
    { "sWidth": "90px"  }
     ],

});
```

When I tried to use "sWidth" with "aoColumnDefs".

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
    { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] }
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set the table width first then it should work

```
<table class="mydataTable" style="width: 650px;">
```

Comment: Okey. Then can you first calculate the percentage and then put it in the datatable as a pixel value. That will work. Percentage is always trouble.

Comment: I edited my post but nothing change again :(.
What is strange is that the 'search' bar just above the header of my table takes the length of the screen and its size does not change, while the table size is growing up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this definition to the CSS, helps to make the `sWidth` effective

```
table#customTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```